# Create new file with ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

In IdeaVIM how do we create new file within the current path ? I used to use `:e` to create a new file, but it doesn't work the same way with ideaVim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can enter `:action NewFile` to use build-in new file function

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The IdeaVim can use lots of built-in function by entering `:action func_name`  use `:actionlist` to find func_name you could use